# Comment « ne » et « que » se sont-ils combinés pour signifier « seulement » ?

Tags: grammaire, étymologie, négation

> [*Ne … que*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) (valeur exceptive ou restrictive) [=] Ne ... rien d'autre que, seulement.

1. Voyez la question intitulée SVP.
2. Ici, que signifient *ne* et *que* ?
3. Étymologiquement, qu'explique le positionnement variable de *que* dans « ne… que » ?

Comment: *ne* et *que* ne se sont pas combinés pour signifier *seulement* ce sont simplement des mots ayant un sens équivalent. De quel variabilité parles-tu pour *que*? Personnellement, je ne vois pas d'autre positionnement possible.

Comment: @YohannV. Sur la `variabilité`, je réfère à : Je ne veux qu'obtenir X vs Je ne veux obtenir que X. Mieux ? Comment appelle-t-on cette `variabilité`?

Comment: Tu modifies ton complément, ce sur quoi porte l'action. Dans le premier, tu mets l'accent sur l'obtention, dans le second sur ce que tu veux obtenir. Je ne connais pas le terme.

Comment: cf http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1246/37

Answer (score 3):

En tant que francophone mal lettré, je n'y vois qu'une évolution logique liée aux tournures : *ne ... pas, ne ... point, ne ... plus, ne ... jamais, ne ... que* :

> *ne* = interdire **...** (l'action)
>
> - *pas* (au présent, dans l'instant),
> - *point* (= *pas*, soutenu),
> - *plus* (jamais dans l'avenir),
> - *jamais* (absolu),
> - *que* (dans telle limite).

Le *que* passe les interdictions ‘absolues’ des quatre premiers à une limitation de l'action ; on passe d'un tout à une subdivision de ce tout désignée par ce *que*.

C'est le *que* « Qui désigne une personne ou une chose ».

Pour reprendre l'exemple cité :

> « Ce *ne* sont *que* des mots » →  « Ils sont *seulement* des mots » → « Ils sont *dans la limite des* mots ».

---

*<sup>Références extraites du petit Robert</sup>*